# Get pixel position from bearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I need to position a dot on a coordinate system based on its bearing and radius.

Using the following code i can position a dot at the correct distance from the center, but this only works horizontally.

What i need is both top & left position of the dot based on bearing & radius

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var km2show = 100;
    var testDistance = 50;
    var width = $('#radar').width();        // Width & height of radar
    var center = width/2;                               // Radar center
    var px2km = center/km2show;                 // Pixels per km
    var radius = radius2coor((px2km*testDistance),center);
    var bearing = 45;
    // Set height of radar based on the width
    $('#radar').height(width);
    // Set dot in center of radar
    $('#centerDot').css({top: center, left: center});

    $('#container').append("<div style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:"+radius+"px;color:white;'>*</div>");
},100);

function radius2coor(radius,center) {
    var res = radius-center;
    return res;
}
```

Please see 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k0fp4no/1/)

So how would i go about getting bot top and left position of the dot ?

The end result should position the dot at the red marker having a bearing of 45 degrees:
[image]

Comment: please set up a function with inputs and outputs clearly defined. This will make helping you a lot easier for someone. Right now I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: I am basically trying to position a dot in a circle based on distance and bearing. What i need to get is the top & left pixel coordinate.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused by the radius2coor function. I think you should explain how exactly distance is to be calculated. Are we supposed to calculate distance to center dot given two coordinates or is this distance previously defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you were encountering was that the angle wasn't in radians so first thing we want is to convert the 45 degrees to pi/4.

Also, when going from regular angular coordinates to x,y coordinates you multiply the radius by sine of the angle to find y coordinate and you multiply the radius by the cosine of the angle to get the x coordinate. Just think about the unit circle and it will make sense.

```js
var bearing = parseInt(prompt("enter angle in degrees", "0"));

if(!isNaN(bearing)){
setTimeout(function() {
 var km2show = 100;
    var testDistance = 50;
 var width = $('#radar').width();  // Width & height of radar
 var center = width/2;        // Radar center
 var px2km = center/km2show;     // Pixels per k
  
    //not sure what this is doing so I set a random radius 
    //(called it distanceFromCenter). If you need this to be 
    //the distance between two cartesian points then you can 
    //just implement the distance formula.
    //var radius = radius2coor((px2km*testDistance),center);
  
    var radius = 100;
    var radianBearing = (bearing/180)*Math.PI
 // Set height of radar based on the width
 $('#radar').height(width);
 // Set dot in center of radar
 $('#centerDot').css({top: center, left: center});
  
  //the main issue you were encountering was that the angle wasn't in radians so I converted it.
  positionDot(radius, radianBearing);
},100);
}
function positionDot(distanceFromCenter, bearing, width)
{

  //when going from regular angular coordinates to x,y coordinates you multiply the radius by sine of the angle to find y coordinate and you multiply the radius by the cosine of the angle to get the x coordinate.
 $('#container').append("<div style='position:absolute;top:"+(-distanceFromCenter*Math.sin(bearing)).toString()+"px;left:"+distanceFromCenter*Math.cos(bearing)+"px;color:white;'>*</div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='radar' style='width:100%;max-width:400px;height:400px;border:1px black solid;border-radius:400px;background-color:#3c3c3c;position:relative;'>

 <div id='centerDot' style='position:absolute;color:white;'>
  <div style='position:relative;' id='container'></div>
  <b>*</b>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. I converted bearing to radian and now it seems to work. Only problem is that 90 degree seems to be 0 in the representation

Comment: can you explain further what you mean by 0? Is it in the center? I have changed my answer to allow you to input whatever angle you like to see. If you converted 90 to radians you should get pi/2, which would result in a second star directly above the center star.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with:
x = center + radius * cos(bearing)
y = center + radius * sin(bearing)

and as MBo said, you have to convert bearing into radians

rad = deg * PI / 180

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sr/8/85/Trig-funkcije1.gif

Comment: Getting closer, but take a look at this fiddle. The distance to center is not correct when using tan(bearing). It is increasing: https://jsfiddle.net/4k0fp4no/2/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I changed the answer

Comment: I think perhaps my approach is wrong here, as the bearing probably also needs to affect "left"...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but i was thinking that radius represents cathetus.

Answer (score 0):

To get both coordinates, you need coordinates of center, radius and bearing.

Note that trigonometric functions usually work with argument in radians, not degrees (don't know about javascript math library)

```
P.X = Center.X + Radius * Math.Cos(bearing)
P.Y = Center.Y + Radius * Math.Sin(bearing)
```